# Enforcing writing across full width of page whilst using the res document class

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, margins, resume

I am using `\documentclass[margin]{res}` to display the section titles of my document to the left of the body text and the `section{Section_name}` command works fine.

However, I would like for some section titles to appear across the entire width of the page and not just in the left margin (causing the text to sometimes overlap with subsequent section titles, in case they span over a few lines in the margin).

I've been using this [template](http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/res2.tex).

Comment: Please add a complete MWE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could insert the section title in a box and manually correct for the mis-alignment on the right-hand side/column:

[image]

```
%...
\section{\makebox[\textwidth][l]{Academic Honors and a Whole Bunch of Other Stuff}}
\mbox{}\\ Dean's List of Distinguished Students, all semesters \\
National Merit Scholarship \\
Alan T.\ Hundert Memorial Scholarship \\
Epsilon Delta Sigma, Honorary Management Society
%...
```

`\mbox{}` puts nothing in that line in order to manually break it. For something that is longer than one line, you could use a `\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{...}`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your useful reply and apologies for my late feedback! The instructions in your answer led exactly to fixing the issue.